# How to understand the closure in different sets?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Problem: Let $(X, \rho)$ be a metric space and $Y,E\subset X$.
If $Y$ is open, show that $cl_{Y}(E\ \cap Y)=cl_{X}(E)\ \cap Y$

And when I think about the problem, I am stuck in thinking "Is $(0,1)$ closed in $(0,1)$ or is $(0,0.5)$ closed in the $(0,1)$?" . I know that $(0,1)$ is closed in the $R$.

What is the closure in different sets?

I am sorry to ask this problem, but I am very confused.

Comment: If $Y \subset X$, then usually the topology we put on $Y$ is that of the subspace topology. In that case, the closure of any set $S \subset Y$ is the smallest set $S'$ containing $S$, such that $S' \cap Y$ is closed in $X$.

Comment: This does not answer your question, but I think in this case you might benefit from being told a few facts; at least then you'll know what's true, and you can use this to help you understand the definitions. With the usual, Euclidean metric: $(0,1)$ is closed in $(0,1);$ $(0,0.5)$ is not closed in $(0,1),$ but $(0,0.5]$ is closed in $(0,1);$ and $(0,1)$ is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$ (for example, $x_{n}=\frac{1}{n}$ $(n\in\mathbb{N})$ is a sequence in $(0,1)$ which converges in $\mathbb{R}$ to $0\not\in(0,1)$).

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Thanks, after thinking about the subspace topology, I make it clear.

Comment: @WillR OK, after the example, I have understanded. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This question doesn't need metric spaces. Since the question was tagged with general topology, I will assume that you know basic topology.

**Hints**:

(1) Notice that in a topological space $(X, \mathcal{T})$, $cl_\mathcal{T}(A)$ is the smallest closed set that contains the set $A$. That it is the smallest, implies that it is unique.

This follows from the fact that the closure is the intersection of all closed sets that contain $A$. You either have this available as a definition, or you should prove it.

(2) Show that $cl_X(E) \cap Y$ is the smallest closed set **in the subspace $Y$** that contains $E\cap Y$. To show this, you will need the definition of subspace topology. Then use uniqueness.

Comment: Thanks, I get it. The subspace topology is the key. Thanks very much

Comment: Np! If my answer helped you, you may accept it if your question is solved.